# Shaded package tries to find java.time.LocalTime in java 7

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa, maven-shade-plugin

We've got a multi-project application that runs under : maven, spring 4.2.7, spring-data-jpa 1.10.2, hibernate 5.1

Everything runs fine when running through eclipse but once we try to shade into a single jar hibernate seems to think we're in java 8 and is looking for `java.time.LocalTime`.

- No use of the java 8 time API is made through whole application
- Everything is configured to run through java 7 (in pom files, console, eclipse)
- I've tried the threetenbp package with the packageToScan injection on the entity manager with no success

Stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:....jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalTime not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.gvh.dsn.ficheParametrage.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalTime not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:819)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.extractAttributeConverterParameterizedType(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.from(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.applyScanResultsToManagedResources(ScanningCoordinator.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:50)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalTime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 36 more
```

Maven shade config :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is my applicationcontext :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="..." />

    <bean id="myContactDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="..." />
        <property name="username" value="..." />
        <property name="password" value="..." />
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myContactDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dalPU" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="dal.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

What am I missing ?

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments

Aggregated POM

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j / log4j2 : Log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `java.time.LocalTime` is introduced in java-8

Comment: Yeah and that's why I don't understand why it's looking for it. The packages are not even compatible with java 8 and everything is set to run under java 7. We do not use `java.time` package anywhere.

Comment: It looks if your applicationContext.xml tries to intializie a bean with that...?

Comment: I don't think so ? Just added my applicationContext in the question.

Comment: What's in `spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` files?

Comment: Can you post the dependency you are using for the PostgreSql driver? Or your whole POM?

Comment: Do you use the Jadira Framework?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the xml code when you try to set the packagestoscan. Can you try the following code if you have not already done it like this    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten"/> namely can you org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten instead of org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threetenbp

Comment: @DraganBozanovic `spring.handlers` has a whole bunch of things like `http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler` and `spring.schemas` just some XSD of spring components.

Comment: @Tunaki Included aggregated POM into the question

Comment: @Periklis I don't use the Jadira Framework, I've tried going with `threeten` and `threetenbp` on the `packagesToScan` property with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Hibernate is doing some classpath scanning and is finding some classes that reference the missing Java 8 time API.  At least some of the class files in your classpath contain references to Java 8 time types.  Using your pom and doing:

`mvn dependency:unpack-dependencies`

followed by:

`grep -R java.time.LocalTime target/dependency | perl -p -e 's#Binary file target/dependency/(.*)\.class.*#$1#'`

I came up with this list of stuff on your classpath that references the Java 8 time API:

```
org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/threeten/Jsr310JpaConverters$LocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters$DateToLocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters$LocalTimeToDateConverter
org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/TemporalAccessorParser
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters$LocalDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters$CalendarToLocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeFormatterRegistrar
org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory
```

The stuff in `org.springframework.format` is used by Spring for type conversions, I don't think it's ever used by Hibernate at all.  My guess is that the offending packages are `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert` and `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten`.

Are you referencing any of those packages or classes directly in your configuration?  Have you tried narrowing your `@EntityScan` or `@ComponentScan` to just packages that contain your code?

Comment: It was indeed `spring-data-jpa` version `1.10.2` which needed java 8 time API. Downgraded to version `1.7.4` and it works ! Huge thanks.

Comment: And to answer your last question, it is the case, spring only scans packages where our own code is.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA and added all your dependencies.

Then I opened the POMs which belong to the dependencies of Hibernate.

In the POM of `org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA` I found this:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <testSource>1.8</testSource>
      <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
      <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I think the test sources are the reason for your issue. When you run the app in Eclipse, there are no tests performed. But when you build with Maven, then all your tests are executed (if you don't use the specific switch `-DskipTests` )

**EDIT**: perhaps to fast... the sources of javassist are not compiled during your build.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate dependency has a method that relies on it which gives you the error.

Additionally hibernate-entitymanager has been deprecated and superseded by hibernate-core